# i want to remove long press mode popup in specific key

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, popup, key

I have a list of keys in my keyboard, this is an example of one of the key:

```
            <Key
            android:codes="45"
            android:keyLabel="-"
            android:keyWidth="20%p"
            android:isModifier="true"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
```

i want to remove the popup function. how i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant you don't want the key icon preview so you need to use this code (after you implement `OnKeyboardActionListener`:

```
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    if (primaryCode==-2||primaryCode==-5||primaryCode==-4){
        mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I did not explain myself correctly, i want to remove the longPress function on specific key. When nothing happens when I press and hold the key in my keboard.

Answer (score 0):

In your keyboard code put this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode) {
    if (keyCode==desiredCode){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you, if not, maybe you have something like this in your xml:

```
android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup" 
android:popupCharacters="uúùũûü"
```

just remove it